# Compare overlap of line segments with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to generate a plot to compare line segments that I have generated using various methods.

I have been playing around with geom_segment of the ggplot2 package but am having trouble achieving what I wish.

Here is some dummy data

```
mat <- matrix(c("a", 2296034, 2296421, "a", 2296982, 2297025, "g", 2295308, 2295991), nrow=3, byrow=T)
df <- data.frame(mat)
```

I would like to plot "a" and "g" as my "y-values" and then visualize the overlap of the line segments.

Here is what I have tried so far but it is not working. I also am hoping to do this with a much larger data set to try and identify which methods converge on the same segments. I would like the x axis to reflect genomic coordinates so it needs to be continuous.

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=X1)) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(2294531,2306989)) + geom_segment(aes(x=X2, y=X1, xend=X2, yend=X1))
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Other than making `xend = X3` (I think?), your main problem is that your continuous variables are currently all factors.  Compare the structure of your `df` to `data.frame(X1 = c("a", "a", "g"), X2 = c(2296034, 2296982, 2295308), X3 = c(2296421, 2297025, 2295991))`.

Comment: Yes, indeed I had a typo in there. You are correct - my variables were factors - easy fix!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aosmith pointed out, my variables were factors and this is why I was having trouble. Also, I made a typo specifying xend=X2 when I meant to put xend=X3.

Here is what the plot looks like if others are trying to generate something similar (note this is with more data points than in my "dummy data").

[image]